# YUM UPDATE stuck forever

Tags: rhel, yum, repository

I created repository for RHEL 5.6. There was already an existing repository for RHEL 5.2 which I deleted.

I ran the following commands:

```
yum clean all

yum clean metadata
```

then,

```
yum list all
```

It list all the packages.

But when I type YUM UPDATE. It shows

```
Setting up Update Process
Setting up repositories
rhel-local                100% |=========================|  951 B    00:0
Reading repository metadata in from local files
primary.xml.gz            100% |=========================| 1.1 MB    00:0
################################################## 3229/3229
Setting up Update Process
Setting up repositories
Reading repository metadata in from local files
```

And that's all folks.  There is no further response from YUM UPDATE.

Any idea why yum is getting stuck?

Comment: you could try to check with strace to see if it is actually doing something.

Answer (score 12):

You could also rebuilt the RPM database.

```
yum clean all
rpm --rebuilddb
```

Comment: Run across this problem before, the above fixed it.

Answer (score 10):

In my case I had a RPM db lock that was getting the yum stuck.

Running `strace yum --verbose --noplugins info` would get stuck at:

```
open("/var/lib/rpm/.dbenv.lock", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0644) = 5
umask(022)                              = 022
fcntl(5, F_SETLKW, {type=F_WRLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0,  len=0}Killed
```

so to fix it I ran as root:

```
rm /var/lib/rpm/.dbenv.lock
```

Comment: ahah: problem is if you don't have strace installed and you can't install because yum is not working (in my case even rpm is broken)

Comment: this helped for me. In my case it wasn't really stuck but you couldn't tell until you used strace. it looked like it was stuck on updating kernel-debug-devel, turns out it just has a lot to do!

Answer (score 4):

This can typically occur if there is either another `yum` process already running or the meta data that `yum` maintains on the system has gotten corrupt.

For the first issue, I usually kill any existing yum processes and then run this command `yum-complete-transaction`, which should allow yum to clean yup after itself.

For the second issue, I usually have to run a `yum clean all` to expunge any meta data cruft and packages and then run a `yum update` as normal.

Occasionally I've also run this command, `package-cleanup <options>` to clean up different issues with the RPM database:

- clean up any duplicate packages (Scan for duplicates in the local RPM database and clean out the older versions)

  ```
  package-cleanup --cleandupes
  ```
- scan for problems (List dependency problems in the local RPM database. If any problems are found it will exit with an exit code of 1)

  ```
  package-cleanup --problems
  ```
- List orphans. (List  installed  packages which are not available from currenly configured repositories. This is identical to `yum list extras`, which may provide better output)

  ```
  package-cleanup --orphans
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the help Actually it I waited for some time for YUM to run. And after 10 mins it started working. I will use your advice on another server and will let your know.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered iscsi error messages in /var/log/messages. And then I stopped iscsi and iscid daemons. After that yum completed the update process.